margenes simetricos con fpdf PDF_WriteTag
Buen día, alguno tendrá algún ejemplo de margenes simétricos en FPDF, básicamente lo que necesito es que la primera hoja tenga unos margenes y la segunda tenga otros margenes, la tercera tenga los margenes de la primera y la cuarta tenga los margenes de la segunda y así sucesivamente, de forma dinámica.
Este es mi código:
$pdf=new PDF_WriteTag('P','mm', array(215.9,342.9));
$pdf->SetTopMargin(78);
$pdf->SetLeftMargin(52);
$pdf->SetRightMargin(19);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true,36); 
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetStyle("p","arial","N",12,"000,000,000",0);
$pdf->SetStyle("h1","arial","N",12,"102,0,102",0);
$pdf->SetStyle("a","arial","BU",12,"0,0,255");
$pdf->SetStyle("pers","arial","I",12,"255,0,0");
$pdf->SetStyle("place","arial","U",12,"153,0,0");
$pdf->SetStyle("vb","arial","B",12,"102,153,153");
$pdf->SetStyle("strong","arial","B",12,"000,000,000");
$pdf->SetLineWidth(24);
$txt="<p>".$html."</p>";
$pdf->SetLineWidth(0);
$pdf->SetFillColor(000,000,000);
$pdf->SetDrawColor(0,0,0);
$pdf->WriteTag(0,10,$txt,0,"J",0,0);

gracias por sus respuestas.

En resumen que tus páginas pares tengan un set de margenes y las impares tengan otro, para eso debes usar la funcion mod (%) en php, si mod es 1 entoces es impar y si mod es 0 entonces es par en base a ese resultado debes crear un IF indicando que tus margenes son tales u otros.

y tendrias que agregar pagina a pagina el contenido, al mismo tiempo aplicas los margenes, eso puede hacerce con un bucle...
